# Can't filter deep array object in computed with Vue in a table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, computed-properties

I have been trying a lot of ways to filter the data, like using only methods or watchers but I can't achieve what I want. Basically, when I search for something in the input I want only the table to display that item and its way to it. Now I'm trying with computed and I get always an error saying 'filter of undefined' and things like that. This is my computed:

```
computed: {
filterData() {
  return this.testData.filter(
    data =>
      !this.search ||
      data.building.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
      data.children.some(item =>
        item.floor.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      )
  );
}}
```

And this is my data to filter:

```
data: () => ({
search: "",
testData: [
  {
    id: 1,
    building: "foo 1",
    children: [
      { id: 11, floor: "bar 1" },
      { id: 12, floor: "bar 2" },
      {
        id: 13,
        floor: "bar 3",
        children: [
          {
            id: 131,
            door: "cor 1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    building: "foo 2",
    children: [
      { id: 21, floor: "bar 3" },
      { id: 22, floor: "bar 4" },
      {
        id: 23,
        floor: "bar 5",
        children: [
          {
            id: 231,
            door: "cor 2"
          },
          {
            id: 232,
            door: "cor 3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I created a sandbox in order to make more easy my explanation => https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-paper-vwes5

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see any error in the codesandbox, it seems to be working.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I was wrong, filtering works, but your data are very similar, so entering eg. "bar" will seem to do nothing. You need to enter like "foo 2" or "4" or "5" to see effect.

Comment: `!this.search` is only true if there is no search, it's false with any text

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Still for some reason it works like this when I changed it like this in the provided codesandbox.

Comment: Maybe there are some limitations to what computed property can detect - in this case it could have been nested too deep? That's my guess, I remember having issues like this with complex computed properties. Documentation unfortunately isn't very helpful in explaining what are conditions of a computed property to be triggered.

Comment: The code already works as is, your edit does the same thing as the existing code.  It's not clear what he wants changed.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My guess is that there are too many similar data. If you don't input a very unique character (like "5") filter seems to do nothing. It did confuse me.